# Plot geom_histogram as points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data:

```
> head(df10)
  Gen_X_ray_h Component
1           0   Housing
2           0   Housing
3           0   Housing
4           0   Housing
5           0   Housing
6           0   Housing
```

and this plot:

[image: 1]

Due to confidential data I removed the legend. I would like to get a better view about how these factors develop over time like whether they are rising or increasing which is rather difficult to see here.
Thing is, when I replace `geom_histogram()` with `geom_point()` I have to add an `y`-argument. Actually, I would like to keep this setting where I can see the count against the time (and also change the `binwidth`).
The syntax is:

```
ggplot(alpha = 0.75) + 
  geom_histogram(df10, mapping = aes(x = Gen_X_ray_h, fill = Component)
                 , binwidth = 500
                 , color = "black"
                 ) +
  labs(title = "Failures") +
  xlab("radiation hours / h") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend("")) +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 28) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

How do I get `counts` vs `radiation hours` for multiple factors visualized as points and/or lines?

edit: some more data:

```
dput(df10[1:60,])
structure(list(Gen_X_ray_h = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 
5, 5, 6.19999999999999, 10, 12.2, 14, 24, 24, 24), Component = c("Housing", 
"Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", 
"Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", 
"HV_Board", "HV_Board", "HV_Board", "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode", 
"HV_Diode", "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode", 
"HV_Resistor", "HV_Resistor", "HV_Resistor", "HV_Resistor", "HV_Transformer", 
"HV_Transformer", "HV_Transformer", "Tube", "Tube", "Tube", "Tube", 
"Tube", "Tube", "Tube", "Tube", "Tube", "Tube_crack", "Tube_crack", 
"Tube_crack", "Tube_crack", "Tube_crack", "Tube_crack", "Tube_crack", 
"Housing", "HV_Board", "Tube", "Housing", "HV_Transformer", "HV_Diode", 
"HV_Diode", "HV_Resistor", "HV_capac", "Housing", "Tube", "Tube_crack"
)), row.names = c(NA, 60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share some more reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten Hi, unfortunately, no as dput would show all the data. However, I added a part of the dataframe but actually the df consists only of two columns of which one is a numeric and the other a factor with 9 levels. Does this help?

Comment: FYI: You could provide a subset via dput, e.g. `dput(df10[1:32,])`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of these options to get the points with counts.

I've used ggplot2's `cut_interval` to get bins with equal range. You could use `cut_width` to get a specified width or `cut_number` to make groups with equal numbers. And you could adjust the number of bins.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Gen_X_ray_h = c(
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3.5, 3.5,
  5, 5, 6.19999999999999, 10, 12.2, 14, 24, 24, 24
), Component = c(
  "Housing",
  "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing",
  "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing",
  "HV_Board", "HV_Board", "HV_Board", "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode",
  "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode", "HV_Diode",
  "HV_Resistor", "HV_Resistor", "HV_Resistor", "HV_Resistor", "HV_Transformer",
  "HV_Transformer", "HV_Transformer", "Tube", "Tube", "Tube", "Tube",
  "Tube", "Tube", "Tube", "Tube", "Tube", "Tube_crack", "Tube_crack",
  "Tube_crack", "Tube_crack", "Tube_crack", "Tube_crack", "Tube_crack",
  "Housing", "HV_Board", "Tube", "Housing", "HV_Transformer", "HV_Diode",
  "HV_Diode", "HV_Resistor", "HV_capac", "Housing", "Tube", "Tube_crack"
)), row.names = c(NA, 60L), class = "data.frame")


# Points
df |> 
  mutate(cut_hours = cut_interval(Gen_X_ray_h, 10)) |> # or cut_width or cut_number
  count(cut_hours, Component) |> 
  ggplot(aes(cut_hours, n, colour = Component)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Failures", x = "binned radiation hours / h", colour = NULL)
```

[image]

```r
# Facets
df |> 
  mutate(cut_hours = cut_interval(Gen_X_ray_h, 10)) |> # or cut_width or cut_number
  count(cut_hours, Component) |> 
  ggplot(aes(cut_hours, n, colour = Component)) +
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ Component, ncol = 2) +
  labs(title = "Failures", x = "binned radiation hours / h", colour = NULL) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>